# opening multiple urls using batch file

Tags: url, batch-file

```
start "" "https://www.yahoo.com/"
start "" "https://www.google.com/"
```

I am using above code in a batch file for opening multiple URLs at a time in different tabs of the browser. However, some URLs are skipped while running batch file. I want all of the URLs to be opened.

Can we slow down the process of opening URLs?

Answer (score 0):

`Timeout /t 1` will make the script wait one second before continuing, if that helps.