# How to open multiple urls in a browser like Chome using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, url

I have several URLs and I want to open them using a batch file. I used this simple script in a file called `URL.bat` to open the webpages when I double click on it. It is working but I want to add a delay of three seconds between each URL because they open all at once which freezes up the machine. I tried to use `timeout` or a delay function but no luck. They are opened all at once again. Below is how I tried to do it, with and without the timeout.

Please note that there is a question with the same problem but I already tried the answer in it and it is not working: [opening multiple urls using batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223751/opening-multiple-urls-using-batch-file)

First attempt:

```
@echo off
start chrome "http://google.com" 
start chrome "http://yahoo.com" 
start chrome "http://bing.com"
```

Second attempt:

```
@echo off
start chrome "http://google.com" 
Timeout 3
start chrome "http://yahoo.com" 
Timeout 3
start chrome "http://bing.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your provided script works on my Win10 machine.
Since Win 7 the `timeout` command is standard, before it's been been provided in some kessource kits.
There is also a `sleep` command which cannot be bypassed by pressing a key.

For more sophisticated batch processing you may have a look at the [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) software- AutoHotkey is a free, open-source macro-creation and automation software for Windows that allows users to automate repetitive tasks. It allows you e.g. to wait for the window until it is loaded and then proceed with the next step. Look for the `WinWait` command.

Comment: I'm using windows 8 machine and it is not working and tried the solutions here as well but no luck. I'm not sure if Autohotkey is a good solution becsaue I have a lot of links

Comment: ahk scripts can be written easily in standard text editors or with help of the macro recorder `autoscriptwriter` which is included in the package.

Comment: It is working great, thank you very much. It is my first time using AHK, but it is a fantastic program with really simple scripting method. Here is how It works:
   ' ^L::
    run www.bing.com
    Sleep, 3000
    run www.google.com
    Sleep, 3000
    run www.yahoo.com'
thanks @Frank

Answer (score 5):

Starting three instances of *Chrome* without delay is an issue which could be solved with a delay of several seconds between.

But why are not opened all three URLs in one instance of *Chrome*?

```
start "" chrome.exe "http://google.com" "http://yahoo.com" "http://bing.com"
```

Yes, it is possible to specify multiple URLs on command line on starting *Chrome*.

Please note that `""` defines an optional console window title which is an empty string in this case as *Google Chrome* is a Windows GUI application and therefore no console window is opened for which a non-empty window title would make sense. The command **START** interprets the first double quoted argument string as optional window title. It is advisable to always specify one for that reason even on being an empty one because of a GUI application is started and not a console application.

Well, there is no batch file needed at all for starting *Google Chrome* with three URLs. There can be made on Windows desktop or in Windows start menu a copy of the shortcut file of *Google Chrome* by clicking once on this shortcut, pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and next <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>. Then the copy can be right clicked and with **Rename** in opened context menu renamed to a meaningful name. Next the properties window of the shortcut must be opened with one more right click on the renamed shortcut and left click in context menu on the last item **Properties**. The property **Target** must be modified by appending the URLs each enclosed in `"` separated with a space from *Google Chrome* executable file name and from the other URLs. The property **Comment** displayed as tooltip below the mouse pointer on hovering the mouse pointer over the shortcut should give also a meaningful hint what this shortcut does on double clicking it. Click **OK** and the shortcut is ready to start *Google Chrome* with opening all the URLs specified on property **Target**.

The advantage of using a shortcut file instead of a batch file: There is no console window displayed shortly as there is started directly *Google Chrome* by *Windows File Explorer* instead of starting first the *Windows Command Processor* for processing the batch file just starting *Google Chrome*.

Answer (score 1):

For **Windows 10/8/7/2008/2012** open **3** **tabs** google chrome with delay 3 sec:

```
@echo off
start "" chrome "https://google.com" 
Timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul 2>&1
start "" chrome "https://yahoo.com" 
Timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul 2>&1
start "" chrome "https://bing.com"
```

For **Windows XP** open **3** **tabs** google chrome applications with delay 3 sec:

```
@echo off
start "" chrome "https://google.com" 
ping timeout -n 1 >nul 2>&1
start "" chrome "https://yahoo.com" 
ping timeout -n 1 >nul 2>&1
start "" chrome "https://bing.com"
```

> Remember to use **""** before chrome to add URL as a tabs.

Comment: `ping timeout -n 1 >nul 2>&1` results in an immediate continuation of batch processing on Windows XP as well as on later Windows. Correct would be `%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n 4 >nul` for a delay of 3 seconds.

Comment: It opened all three at once, I'm using windows 8. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Thank You @kgimpel , this works , used full path instead of "chrome". Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The timeout isn't working for you because you got the syntax for the timeout command wrong, try this:

```
@echo off
start chrome  "http://google.com" 
Timeout /t 3
start chrome  "http://yahoo.com" 
Timeout /t 3
start chrome  "http://bing.com"
```

This will wait 3 seconds before opening the next URL, though 3 seconds might be too quick, try making it 5, or even more, maybe 10.

Comment: As you can see when using `timeout /?`, the /t is not necesary and `timeout 3` works perfectly fine. That is why it says `TIMEOUT [/T] timeout [/NOBREAK]` instead of `TIMEOUT [/T timeout] [/NOBREAK]`

Comment: @DennisvanGils I don't know, never tried it without the `/T` , he still claims it didn't work the way he did it without the `/T` , Maybe he's on an old OS, either way, it could be just that 3 isn't enough, because it still opens the next URL before the last one finished loading, 5 or maybe 10 seconds will work better.

Comment: I think that's probably it, he's trying to load the next page to fast after the previous. That's probably because opening his browser from nothing takes longer than loading a new tab in an already open browser.

Comment: tried it with /t and without it, with delay, with no break, tried several variations of the script but no luck.